# How to convert a generator to a list?

Tags: generators, loop-facility

I'm a huge fan of using generators all the time and for everything, but sometimes you just need to convert an iterator to a list.

The [documentation on generators](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Generators.html) seems to imply this is doable with the loop facility

> The Common Lisp loop facility also contains features for working with iterators. See Loop Facility in Common Lisp Extensions.

Yet I cannot find anything about generators or iterators in the [loop facility](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Loop-Facility.html#Loop-Facility) docs.

I assumed that something like this would work

```
  (iter-defun gim/playground/a-generator-function ()
    (iter-yield 5)
    (iter-yield 9)
    (iter-yield -28))
  
  (cl-loop for x in (gim/playground/a-generator-function) collect x)
```

But it doesn't seem to iterate the generator result, just the list that *represents* the iterator. So how do I

1. Elegantly convert an iterator to a list (yes, assuming it is finite and possible)
2. Use the loop facility with iterators

Comment: Use `iter-by`. `(cl-loop for x iter-by (GENERATOR) collect r)`.

Comment: Goodness, yes now I see it at the bottom of the "iteration clauses" page, just didn't see it and it was weird that the generator doc pointed to a page that didn't have the information